# Why isn't "head -1" equivalent with "head -n -1" but instead it's the same as "head -n 1"?

Tags: linux, head

`head -num` is the same as `head -n num` instead of `head -n -num` (where `num` is any number)

Example:

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd'|head -1
a

$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd'|head -n 1
a

$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd'|head -n -1
a
b
c
```

This `head -1` doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

`$ head --help`

```
Usage: head [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Print the first 10 lines of each FILE to standard output.
With more than one FILE, precede each with a header giving the file name.

With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -c, --bytes=[-]NUM       print the first NUM bytes of each file;
                             with the leading '-', print all but the last
                             NUM bytes of each file
  -n, --lines=[-]NUM       print the first NUM lines instead of the first 10;
                             with the leading '-', print all but the last
                             NUM lines of each file
  -q, --quiet, --silent    never print headers giving file names
  -v, --verbose            always print headers giving file names
  -z, --zero-terminated    line delimiter is NUL, not newline
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

NUM may have a multiplier suffix:
b 512, kB 1000, K 1024, MB 1000*1000, M 1024*1024,
GB 1000*1000*1000, G 1024*1024*1024, and so on for T, P, E, Z, Y.

GNU coreutils online help: <https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Full documentation at: <https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/head>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) head invocation'
```

Man page for `head` (on Fedora 28):

```
HEAD(1)                          User Commands                         HEAD(1)

NAME
       head - output the first part of files

SYNOPSIS
       head [OPTION]... [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION
       Print  the  first  10 lines of each FILE to standard output.  With more
       than one FILE, precede each with a header giving the file name.

       With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

       Mandatory arguments to long options are  mandatory  for  short  options
       too.

       -c, --bytes=[-]NUM
              print  the  first  NUM bytes of each file; with the leading '-',
              print all but the last NUM bytes of each file

       -n, --lines=[-]NUM
              print the first NUM lines instead of  the  first  10;  with  the
              leading '-', print all but the last NUM lines of each file

       -q, --quiet, --silent
              never print headers giving file names

       -v, --verbose
              always print headers giving file names

       -z, --zero-terminated
              line delimiter is NUL, not newline

       --help display this help and exit

       --version
              output version information and exit

       NUM may have a multiplier suffix: b 512, kB 1000, K 1024, MB 1000*1000,
       M 1024*1024, GB 1000*1000*1000, G 1024*1024*1024, and so on for  T,  P,
       E, Z, Y.

AUTHOR
       Written by David MacKenzie and Jim Meyering.

REPORTING BUGS
       GNU coreutils online help: <https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
       Report head translation bugs to <https://translationproject.org/team/>

COPYRIGHT
       Copyright  ©  2017  Free Software Foundation, Inc.  License GPLv3+: GNU
       GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
       This is free software: you are free  to  change  and  redistribute  it.
       There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

SEE ALSO
       tail(1)

       Full documentation at: <https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/head>
       or available locally via: info '(coreutils) head invocation'

GNU coreutils 8.29               December 2017                         HEAD(1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The info page and [the online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/head-invocation.html) for GNU `head` contain this part:

> For compatibility `head` also supports an obsolete option syntax
>   `-[NUM][bkm][cqv]`, which is recognized only if it is specified first.

The idea that `head -1` is the same as `head -n 1` is that the dash is not a minus sign, but a marker for a command line option. That's the usual custom: things that start with dashes are options controlling how to do processing, other stuff in the command line are file names or other actual targets to process. In this case, it's not a single-character option, but a shorthand for `-n`, but it's still basically an option, and not a filename. In `head +1` or `head 1`, the `+1` or `1` would be taken as file names, however.

A double dash `--` or `--something` also has a distinct meaning, by itself (`--`) it stops option processing, and when followed by something else, it marks a GNU style long option. So having `head --1` for `head -n -1` wouldn't match the custom.

If I were to guess, I'd assume the quaint shortcut for `-n i` exists for positive `i` but not for negative `i` since the former case is useful more often and easier to implement. (Besides, the [standard `head`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/head.html) is only defined for a positive value of lines.)

Comment: See also the original UNIX man page: http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/head.1.html